# How to fix Intelisense error for Blazor code section?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, resharper, blazor

I'm using Visual Studio 16.3.10 (with Resharper) and .Net Core 3.0 with Server-Side Blazor.
It's a nearly clear template project.

I'm getting this type of errors in all `.razor` files:

[image: Error]

Project is building just fine. And in **Error List** in VS is empty.
Also normal `.cs` files are looking nice and clear.

I haven't found anything by using search etc.

How can I get rid of this *fake* errors?

Comment: Do they persist after a (re)build? What version of .core (3.0 or 3.1) and is your Visual Studio a Preview or not?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately

Comment: Have you restarted VS? Sometimes just rebuilding doesn't help.. Also removing the bin and obj folders before rebuilding is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry I have no fix, but maybe you can try if things improve by putting the `@code` part before the `@page` part...

Comment: I know turning of R# is a bit of a hassle but I suspect that it is the culprit. But this is something you can safely ignore. Blazor is new and quickly evolving.

Comment: Yes, it stays after removing folders, restarting VS and rebuilding.

Comment: Same error @PeterB with Code before Page

Comment: Resharper doesn't support Blazor yet. Try to disable it, and see if the errors are gone

Comment: Turning off Resharper helped. But at what cost

Comment: If this is for learning purposes, you could install the VS Preview (and use the latest Blazor stuff, 3.1) . And then keep R# on in your regular VS.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in Resharper 2019.2.3 and up I believe. If you have 2019.2.3 and it's still not working, I would install the latest EAP here : https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/